# Solve differential in respect to a function rather than a variable

Tags: calculus, analysis

In an exercise I have to solve this differential. Now what confuses me is that we take the derivative in respect to a function rather then a variable. Now I am not sure how to proceed?

$$\frac{d}{d(\cos (\theta))} \cos(n\theta)$$

Comment: If you're interested, I have added two more sections that go into more detail about what is going on here. One of them is about how to express these manipulations using Lagrange's prime notation, which is more formal. The other is about how parameterisation can help you understand this kind of differentiation better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I'd rather call this a 'derivative' as opposed to 'differential'; in my experience, a differential refers to something like '$dy$' or '$dx$' considered on its own.

**Hint**: to solve this problem, use the chain rule:
$$
\frac{d\cos n\theta}{d\cos\theta}=\frac{d\cos n\theta}{d\theta} \cdot \frac{d\theta}{d\cos\theta} \, .
$$

As for your more general question about what
$$
\frac{d\cos n\theta}{d\cos\theta}
$$
actually means, this is a prime example of *implicit differentiation*. The equation
$$
x^2+y^2=1
$$
gives us a simpler example of this. There is no single way to write $y$ as a 'function of $x$'. Either
$$
y(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
or
$$
y(x)=-\sqrt{1-x^2} \, .
$$
Implicit differentiation tells us that regardless of which of these two functions we are considering, the following relationship holds:
$$
\frac{dy(x)}{dx} = -\frac{x}{y(x)} \, .
$$
In your example, it might be difficult or impossible to find an explicit formula connecting $\cos n\theta$ and $\cos \theta$; that is, there is no *single* way to write $\cos n\theta$ as a 'function of $\cos\theta$'. However, we can still find an 'implicit' equation that tells us how $\cos n\theta$ changes for infinitesimal changes in $\cos\theta$, treating $\cos\theta$ as a variable just like any other.

---

In Lagrange notation, these manipulations would read differently. Let $f$ be an arbitrary function satisfying
$$
f(\cos\theta) = \cos n\theta
$$
for all $\cos\theta$. To make this more readable, let $g(\theta)=\cos \theta$. Then,
$$
\cos n \theta = f(g(\theta)) \, .
$$
By the chain rule,
\begin{align}
-n\sin n \theta &= f'(g(\theta))g'(\theta) \\
&= -f'(\cos\theta)\sin\theta
\end{align}
which implies
$$
f'(\cos\theta) = \frac{n\sin n \theta}{\sin\theta} \, .
$$

---

Finally, another way to solve this equation is to *parameterise* $\cos n\theta$ and $\cos \theta$ with respect to $\theta$. In general, parameterisation is where you express two variables $x$ and $y$ in terms of a third variable $t$. In general, if we find two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $x=f(t)$ and $y=g(t)$, then
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=f'(t) \text{ and } \frac{dy}{dt}=g'(t)
$$
which implies that
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{g'(t)}{f'(t)} \, .
$$
In this case, if we let $y=\cos n\theta$ and $x=\cos \theta$, then
$$
\frac{dy}{d\theta}=-n\sin n\theta \text{ and } \frac{dx}{d\theta} = -\sin\theta \, .
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-n\sin(n\theta)}{-\sin\theta}=\frac{n\sin n\theta}{\sin\theta} \, .
$$
This method is in essence the same as the first one I showed you, but it's helpful to get another perspective.